# How to upload files to databse using django in blob?

Tags: django, database, file-upload, binary

I want to create a biometric authentication system, so i need to save bimetric data(thumb image) to database in blob. How to do same using django?

Comment: Have you looked at the docs? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/files/

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `TextField`

```
file = models.TextField(
            db_column='data',
            blank=True)
```